# Add a label for each leaf on the plot of a tree

Tags: r, tree

I have the following dataframe:

```
> data
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
 1  1  1  1  1
 1  1  3  1  1
 1  1  3  2  1
 2  1  1  1  3
 2  2  1  1  1
 2  2  2  2  1
 3  2  3  1  1
 3  2  3  2  1
```

where V1... V4 are the levels of a tree, so each row will represent a leaf in the tree. As we can see, levels V1 and V3 can assume three possible nodes while levels V2 and V4 can have two possibles nodes.

I drew the tree in this way:

```
data$pathString<-paste("0", data$V1,data$V2,data$V3,data$V4,sep = "/")
mytree <- as.Node(data)
export_graph(ToDiagrammeRGraph(mytree), "tree.pdf")
```

The figure stored in pdf is:

[image]

I'm trying to add (on the figure) a label (column V5 of 'data') for each leaf of the tree. For example, starting from the left, the labels under each leaf are respectively: 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1.

Suggestions?

Comment: if its just the V5 it can be done with: `data$pathString<-paste("0", data$V1,data$V2,data$V3,data$V4,data$V5,sep = "/")` what else do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Mankind_008, thank you. I thought the same answer... a "dummy" level (the latest) containing the labels of each leaf. But I wonder if another solution exists...